# SQL Query that only retrieves timestamped (with time zone) rows at 2:00 UTC regardless of Daylight Savings Time

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm sure the title is probably confusing. Couldn't find a way to word this well in the title without making it *very* long.

**In Short**

I have a PSQL database table that archives an external API endpoint every 15 minutes. The table has the following columns:

- id (serial)
- match (jsonb)
- snapshot_time (timestamp with time zone not null default now() )

I need an SQL query that will only fetch rows under the following constraints:

- The day must be saturday (6)
- Timestamp must be at '...T02:00:00Z' ISO8601
- Between specified start and end dates.

**What I currently have**

```
SELECT id,snapshot_time,match->'kills' FROM match_archive 
WHERE extract(dow from snapshot_time)=6 
AND snapshot_time >= '2016-12-01' 
AND date_part('hour', snapshot_time)=2 
AND date_part('minute', snapshot_time)=00;
```

(Start & end time are currently hard coded in for example)

**The Issues**

This returns the correct rows, the issue however is that the resulting rows since the `snapshot_time` column is type `timestamp with time zone` are actually 5 hours off since I live in Eastern Standard Time.

An example row it returns is

```
   id   |         snapshot_time         |                  ?column?
--------+-------------------------------+--------------------------------------------
 120941 | 2016-12-03 02:00:03.32946-05  | {"red": 3389, "blue": 1962, "green": 2911}
```

As you can see, the snapshot_time is indeed 2:00, but it's in EST.

I figured, "hey I could just make it hour: 21, day of week: 5 (friday)", and that would work, but suddenly it'd be an hour off due to Daylight Savings Time in the future.

The other thing would be storing information using `timestamp without time zone` but what happens then is it will take `2016-12-03T17:44:21-05` and just chop off the `-05` and leave it as `2016-12-03T17:44:21Z` when inserting a new row into the database.

So, is there any good way to make an SQL query that will allow me to get rows following the requirements listed above without worrying about Daylight Savings Time? Thanks.

Comment: Although I realize that you may not have had this option, Understand that best practice is to always store date time data in UTC in the first place. If that had been done, this issue would not arise. Even now, if I had the option, I would seriously investigate converting all existing local time  zone date time data (and code that drives off of it) in the database to UTC.,

Comment: @CharlesBretana storing timezones in UTC isn't even a choice in PostgreSQL. That's how they are stored.

Comment: I didn't say store timezones, I said store date times in UTC. I confess that I'm not familiar with PostgreSQL, however.  Are you saying that you have no control over the value you store in a datetime column of a PostGreSQL table? That the client software cannot store a UTC value instead of a local time value?

Comment: No. I'm saying you can only store in UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This returns the correct rows, the issue however is that the resulting rows since the snapshot_time column is type timestamp with time zone are actually 5 hours off since I live in Eastern Standard Time.

Timestamps are always stored in UTC in PostgreSQL, [per the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html)

> For timestamp with time zone, the internally stored value is always in UTC (Universal Coordinated Time, traditionally known as Greenwich Mean Time, GMT). An input value that has an explicit time zone specified is converted to UTC using the appropriate offset for that time zone. If no time zone is stated in the input string, then it is assumed to be in the time zone indicated by the system's TimeZone parameter, and is converted to UTC using the offset for the timezone zone.
>
> When a timestamp with time zone value is output, **it is always converted from UTC to the current timezone zone, and displayed as local time in that zone. To see the time in another time zone, either change timezone or use the AT TIME ZONE construct** (see [Section 9.9.3](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-ZONECONVERT)).

Answer (score 0):

Answering my question in case anyone comes across this question on Google.

Following Evan Carroll's answer, the following SQL fixed my issue:

```
SELECT id,snapshot_time,match->'kills' FROM match_archive 
WHERE extract(dow from snapshot_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')=5 
AND snapshot_time >= '2016-12-01' 
AND date_part('hour', snapshot_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')=2 
AND date_part('minute', snapshot_time AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')=00;
```

Probably not necessary on the minute date_part, but want to be consistent.

Comment: Or just set the local time zone in the client, database, or operating system to UTC if you want times in UTC.